# adding static_pointer_cast<Derived> to a std::list<shared_ptr<Base>> causes pure virtual method called error

Tags: c++, casting, virtual, shared-ptr

I have this Base class

```
class Base {

    std::string nome;

public:
    std::string getName() const;
    virtual int mType() const = 0;
    virtual void ls(int indent=0) const = 0;
};
```

from which I derived this Directory class

```
class Directory : public Base {

private:
    static std::shared_ptr<Directory> root;
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<Base>> childs;
    std::weak_ptr<Directory> parent;
    std::weak_ptr<Directory> thisDirectory;
    std::string nome;

protected:
    Directory(const std::string n);

public:
    static std::shared_ptr<Directory> getRoot();
    std::shared_ptr<Directory> addDirectory(std::string nome);
    std::shared_ptr<File> addFile(std::string nome, uintmax_t size);
    std::shared_ptr<Base> get(std::string name);
    std::shared_ptr<Directory> getDir(std::string name);
    std::shared_ptr<File> getFile(std::string name);
    void remove(std::string nome);

    int mType() const override;
    void ls(int indent=0) const override;
};
```

the method addDirectory

```
std::shared_ptr<Directory> Directory::addDirectory(std::string nome) {
    auto it = std::find_if(childs.begin(), childs.end(), [nome](std::shared_ptr<Base> p){return (p->getName()==nome);});
    if(it == childs.end()){
        std::cout<<"creating "<<nome<<" directory"<<std::endl;
        std::shared_ptr<Directory> p = std::shared_ptr<Directory>(new Directory(nome));
        childs.push_back(std::static_pointer_cast<Base>(p));
        p->parent = std::shared_ptr<Directory>(this);
        std::cout<<nome<<" created"<<std::endl;
        return p;
    }
    else {
        // todo gestione eccezione
        std::cout<<nome<<" already exists"<<std::endl;
        throw std::exception();
    }
}
```

will print this output

```
pure virtual method called
creating root...
terminate called recursively
root created
creating alfa directory
alfa created
```

`pure virtual method called` is caused by `childs.push_back(std::static_pointer_cast<Base>(p));` while `terminate called recursively` is throwed by `p->parent = std::shared_ptr<Directory>(this);`.
Using `childs.push_back(p)` works fine, why?
Is it trying to make an instance of a Base object? Can I manage a list of derived class object by using shared_ptr for the Base class?

Comment: You can’t hand over ownership of `*this` to a `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [enable_shared_from_this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) in order to create a `shared_ptr` from `this`.

Change your class declaration to ...

`class Directory : public Base, public std::enable_shared_from_this<Directory>`

and replace `std::shared_ptr<Directory>(this)` with `shared_from_this()`. Also make sure all directories (including the root) are constructed using shared pointers.

Comment: parent and thisDirectory are weak_ptr

Comment: @TonyRomero `weak_ptr` is contructed from `shared_ptr`, so this is absolutely fine (this is what you did already)